# Is it possible to show a UIViewcontroller in a UITabviewcontroller that doesn't exist in tabs?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uicontainerview

I got a really weird situation; I have a tabviewcontroller that contains 5 tabs, and that tabviewcontroller is in a container that is in a uiviewcontroller which holds top and bottom bars. There are some extra pages and their linked buttons should not be shown in uitabbar, but in the parent uiviewcontrollers' top and bottom bars. When I open those extra pages, tabs, bottom bar and top bar should not disappear, only the container area in the tabviewcontroller should show that extra pages. I use latest version of swift and latest version of xcode.

Any ideas?

Comment: basically you want container View to show Multiple ViewControllers i.e Multiple VC in One ContainerView in single Controller ? is it ?

Comment: That would do. Can you provide some links how to integrate containerview and tabbar, I tried and failed doing that.

Comment: I will create a sample Project for that I had just done half of it not used tabBar for such case

Comment: so flow is UIViewControler -> Bottom Bar & Up Bar & ContainerView -> In Container a TAbbar That will switch multiple tabs in same Container View Bounds only, Correct ?

Comment: I can change inside of a containerview, my real problem is integrating that with tabbar actually.

Comment: Okay will try and let you know

Comment: Maybe this will help - you **don't** show a `UIViewController`. You show - by segue, presenting, or maybe making it the root controller - it's **view**. I'm sensing some confusion on that... the division between a controller and the view it shows. That's probably because you've shown no details... code or otherwise... but maybe not.

Comment: I Posted Answer including a sample Project , check it Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a sample Project Integrating Container View and Tab Bar Controller as you asked

Check - https://github.com/RockinGarg/ContainerView-TabBar.git

ScreenShot

Tab bar VC1 -

[image]

Tab VC2 -

[image]

Other Controller in same ContainerView when Clicked Second fro bottom ToolBar Added

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. I actually made the designer change his mind and now I just did extra pages with a root navigation controller.

Comment: Also I looked at your code and the tabs are gone when I clicked extra page, but it surely fixes my tabbar-containerview problem. So I will keep this in my archive. Thank you again. :)